# 3 routers with three subnets to connect with each other without conflicts

Tags: networking, routing, router, subnet

I have a network environment with three routers:

router #1 uses 192.168.1.x (TP-LINK TL-WR340G using it as switch)

router #2 uses 192.168.3.x (SonicWALL TZ200 using it as DHCP and VPN)

router #3 uses 192.168.100.x (Huawei HG8245Q with high speed internet connection)

What I need is to connect router #3 to both router #1 and #2 and get access to all subnets from any client connect to the network.

Notes:

- Router #3 is connected to the network through another switch with other multiple LAN wires.
- Router #1 and #2 in same location near each other.
- All routers DHCP is enabled with subnet 255.255.255.0
- When I connect with client I got IP from Router #3 while I want all clients to get IP addresses from router #2

I have no experience or educational background on this so please direct me to the right solution, including removing or adding devices, and changing settings in those routers.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know any of the devices you mention, so you have to rely on the manuals of the manufacturer for details.

You are best off with a star-shaped network layout. Connect router #1 and #3 to router #2. Make sure there are no other connections running between your routers, including connections going through switches.

Assign both #1 and #3 on the port connected to #2 an IP address from the network you want to use, in your example probably 192.168.3.0/24 (that's shorthand for 192.168.3.x with a subnet of 255.255.255.0. [Read more here.](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing)) This should already take care of routing between the devices. However, maybe you have to set the other ports to "switchport mode." How to do this depends on the device in question.

If the other switch you mention is "dumb" it will not care and just forward the packages as intended. If not, you might have to configure it, too.

Disable DHCP on routers #1 and #3. Maybe you have to configure them to forward DHCP-traffic.

On #2 enable DHCP but make sure that your default gateway is set to the IP of #3. Otherwise you will not have internet access.

This should get you going. Good luck.

Comment: First thank you. Second, I'm confused because router #2 in question have 5 ports one of them WAN and others all LAN. If am I going to connect router #3 to router #2 in which port WAN or LAN? considering that I have router #3 linked through "dumb" switch which I will use for other LAN devices later.

Comment: I figure it out. I was in need of 2 subnets because of sonic wall does not accept WAN and LAN have same subnets. Other than that it is as you described.